# What is the best practice template for textifying a link not in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: discussion, markdown, hyperlinks, best-practices

I often find myself replacing plain text links in the middle of articles to make them more readable. For example some markdown might have an answer about bespin and added a link at the end or in the middle.
Example:

```
lorum bespin good etc.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bespin
```

What is the ideal way to textify a link in this case?  I looked at some citation information and the best I can come up with is the following template:

```
"[Bespin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bespin)", *wikia.com*

"[<Page_Title>](<link>)", *<website_domain>*
```

But I'm not sure if that's ideal, perhaps it would look better without the quotes, or there is some other preferred style.

What is the best practice format for textifying a floating link reference?

Comment: Why the close votes?  This seems like a pretty valid, and if anything, it is a needed question.  It would be better for the entire stack system if users had some guidance on style.  Npm, for example has a style guide to go with its system, even if not everyone follows it.